# CKEditor default style for styleCommand (format styles with buttons)

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have created a CKEditor plugin which does the base p, h2, h3, h4 formatting with custom buttons (instead of the stylescombo). It works great, but if I uncheck an element (ex. 'h2'), sets the 'div' tag as parent element for the row. I want to be the 'p' as the default element and also the 'p' button can't be unchecked (unless I clicking on another, ex. 'h2' button). How is this possible?

The plugin looks like:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('stylesbuttons_custom',{
    lang:'en',
    icons:'p,h2,h3,h4',
    init:function(editor){
        var order=0;
        var addButtonCommand=function(buttonName,buttonLabel,commandName,styleDefiniton){
                if (!styleDefiniton)
                    return;
                var style=new CKEDITOR.style(styleDefiniton);
                editor.attachStyleStateChange(style,function(state){
                    !editor.readOnly && editor.getCommand(commandName).setState(state);
                });
                editor.addCommand(commandName,new CKEDITOR.styleCommand(style));
                if (editor.ui.addButton){
                    editor.ui.addButton(buttonName,{
                        label:buttonLabel,
                        command:commandName,
                        toolbar:'basicstyles,'+(order+=10)
                    });
                }
            };
        var lang=editor.lang.stylesbuttons_custom;

        addButtonCommand('P',lang.p,'p',{element:'p'});
        addButtonCommand('H2',lang.h2,'h2',{element:'h2'});
        addButtonCommand('H3',lang.h3,'h3',{element:'h3'});
        addButtonCommand('H4',lang.h4,'h4',{element:'h4'});
    }
});
```

I load the plugin like:

`config.extraPlugins='stylesbuttons_custom';`

I put buttons to toolbar like:

`config.toolbar:[['P','H2','H3','H4','Pre']];`

Here is a screenshot about the problem: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross posting my answer from [CKEditor forum](http://ckeditor.com/comment/124380#comment-124380).

I think that you need to write your own command instead of using `CKEDITOR.styleCommand`.

It should work exactly like `CKEDITOR.styleCommand` when style is not yet applied on current selection.

But when clicked again it should apply the paragraph style, not remove the previously applied style. E.g:

```
styleCommand.prototype.exec = function( editor ) {
    editor.focus();

    if ( this.state == CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF )
        editor.applyStyle( this.style );
    else if ( this.state == CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON )
        editor.applyStyle( paragraphStyle );
};
```

PS. I created a ticket: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10190 because I think that removing block style should revert back to paragraph (in `enterMode=P`). For now use the above workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @Reinmar notifies that there is an error in the CKEditor's style.js where the this._.enterMode is not defined.

Doing this on style.js, resolve the problem:

```
this._ = {
  definition: styleDefinition,
  enterMode: CKEDITOR.config.enterMode
};
```

And from now on when a style button is unchecked the block changes to the default 'p' element.

Now my complete working plugin looks like:

```
(function(){
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('custombuttons',{
    lang:'hu,en,de,ro',
    init:function(editor){

        var order=0,t=this,lang=editor.lang.custombuttons;

        // addButtonCommand helper
        var addButtonCommand=function(buttonName,buttonLabel,commandName,styleDefiniton){
            var style=new CKEDITOR.style(styleDefiniton);
            var styleCommand=function(style){
                this.style=style;
                this.allowedContent=style;
                this.requiredContent=style;
                this.contextSensitive=true;
            };
            styleCommand.prototype={
                exec:function(editor){
                    editor.focus();
                    if (this.state==CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF)
                        editor.applyStyle(this.style);
                    else if (this.state==CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON)
                        editor.removeStyle(this.style);
                    if(commandName!='fakecommand'){editor.execCommand('fakecommand');editor.execCommand('fakecommand');} /* hack to change button state properly */
                },
                refresh:function(editor,path){
                    this.setState(path&&this.style.checkApplicable(path)?(this.style.checkActive(path)?CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON:CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF):CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_DISABLED);
                }
            };
            editor.addCommand(commandName,new styleCommand(style));
            if(editor.ui.addButton){editor.ui.addButton(buttonName,{label:buttonLabel,command:commandName,toolbar:'basicstyles,'+(order+=10),icon:t.path+'images/'+commandName+'.png'});}
        };

        // _fakebutton (hack)
        addButtonCommand('_fakebutton','','fakecommand',{element:'span'});

        // style buttons
        addButtonCommand('P',lang.p,'p',{element:'p'});
        addButtonCommand('H2',lang.h2,'h2',{element:'h2'});
        addButtonCommand('H3',lang.h3,'h3',{element:'h3'});
        addButtonCommand('H4',lang.h4,'h4',{element:'h4'});
        addButtonCommand('Pre',lang.pre,'pre',{element:'pre'});
        addButtonCommand('Mini',lang.mini,'mini',{element:'p',attributes:{class:'mini'}});
        addButtonCommand('Important',lang.important,'important',{element:'span',attributes:{class:'important'}});
        addButtonCommand('Comment',lang.comment,'comment',{element:'span',attributes:{class:'comment'}});
        addButtonCommand('Mark',lang.mark,'mark',{element:'mark'});
        addButtonCommand('ImgLeft',lang.imgLeft,'imgLeft',{element:'img',attributes:{class:'imgleft'}});
        addButtonCommand('ImgRight',lang.imgRight,'imgRight',{element:'img',attributes:{class:'imgright'}});
        addButtonCommand('ImgCenter',lang.imgCenter,'imgCenter',{element:'img',attributes:{class:'imgcenter'}});

        // button shortcut keys
        editor.setKeystroke(
        [
            [CKEDITOR.CTRL+48,'p'], // Ctrl+0
            [CKEDITOR.CTRL+49,'h2'], // Ctrl+1
            [CKEDITOR.CTRL+50,'h3'], // Ctrl+2
            [CKEDITOR.CTRL+51,'h4'], // Ctrl+3
        ]);
    }
});
})();
```

There is still a hack in the code. I needed to run a 'fakecommand' to really update (refilter?) the changed tags and all its parent tags. For example the 'p.mini' button caused problems (the state was not updated) when clicked multiple time. So there is still an unelegant solution. Any idea how to force to update or refilter the code after a style is applied?